# Find value of key in one JSON file and replace it with value of key from second JSON where value in first JSON matches key in second JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have two JSON files.

File1

```
{
  "dataSet": "w28h46c7XUD",
  "completeDate": "2018-10-23T14:16:11.384+0000",
  "period": "2018Q3",
  "orgUnit": "tBl4WduwWRw",
  "dataValues": [
    {
     "dataElement": "QRMyfx7WQKa",
     "period": "2018Q3",
     "orgUnit": "zndtyhyYuh6",
     "categoryOptionCombo": "gGhClrV5odI",
     "attributeOptionCombo": "gGhClrV5odI",
     "value": "90",
     "storedBy": "biostatwakiso",
     "created": "2018-10-25T14:52:26.835+0000",
     "lastUpdated": "2018-10-25T14:52:26.835+0000",
     "followUp": false
    },
    {
     "dataElement": "btM76ubdLKE",
     "period": "2018Q3",
     "orgUnit": "Uuv34dh6Hjd",
     "categoryOptionCombo": "Bbb6ZmzRhtO",
     "attributeOptionCombo": "gGhClrV5odI",
     "value": "7",
     "storedBy": "HMISWAKISO",
     "created": "2018-10-11T08:58:32.046+0000",
     "lastUpdated": "2018-10-11T08:58:32.046+0000",
     "followUp": false
    },
    {
     "dataElement": "VCYHJu3BxpN",
     "period": "2018Q3",
     "orgUnit": "PYudhikuj23",
     "categoryOptionCombo": "RbnGbnNxoJF",
     "attributeOptionCombo": "gGhClrV5odI",
     "value": "3",
     "storedBy": "biostatwakiso2018",
     "created": "2018-10-11T08:58:12.787+0000",
     "lastUpdated": "2018-10-23T14:00:17.703+0000",
     "followUp": false
    },
    ...
```

File2

```
{"tBl4WduwWRw" : "ert678dDvk"},
{"zndtyhyYuh6" : "tY67UhdJj8"},
{"Uuv34dh6Hjd" : "O0plYhdjyj"},
{"PYudhikuj23" : "H67JuyghkN"},
```

What i want to achieve is a script that finds the value of the key 'orgUnit' in file1, and replaces it with the value of the key that matches it in file2. 
eg. in file1 find the value of key orgUnit = tBl4WduwWRw and replace it with ert678dDvk from file2.

Comment: Your second file does not appear to be valid JSON. Is it supposed be an array? In any case, this should be easy to do using a combination of [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Just `map()` over `dataValues` and return the same object from the callback function with the key `orgUnit` modified by using `find()` on the other array to find the matching value.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use your own code instead of using any library or available functions. It's just a small code, let's take a look:

```
function handleObject(object, replaceValues) {
    var values = Object.values(object);
    var keys = Object.keys(object);
    for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
        object[keys[i]] = handleReplaceOneValue(values[i], replaceValues);
    }
    return object;
}

function handleArray(array, replaceValues) {
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = handleReplaceOneValue(array[i], replaceValues);
    }
    return array;
}

function handleReplaceOneValue(value, replaceValues) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      return handleArray(value, replaceValues)
    }
    if (value instanceof Object) {
      return handleObject(value, replaceValues)
    }
    return replaceValues[value] ? replaceValues[value] : value;
}
```

Then call:

```
handleObject(YourJSONFile1, YourJSONFile2);
```